# What's the best way to store text data?

Tags: android, android-file

I am kinda new to Android development, but I coded a lot of C#(WinF,WPF). I created an quiz app (German words) for app and I'm not quite sure how to store and load dictionaries (a file, where lines contain 2 words). What is the best way to store these dictionaries? I googled a bit, but didn't find exact answers. At the moment I generate the words directly in the code. 
Thanks!

Comment: You can store it in assests folder and can access the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have just key-value pair i will suggest to create a json from your data, store into assests folder and use at runtime.

For eg. **CountyCode.json**

```
  [
  {
    "country_name": "Canada",
    "country_code": 1
  },
  {
    "country_name": "United States of America",
    "country_code": 1
  },
  {
    "country_name": "US Virgin Islands",
    "country_code": 1
  },
  {
    "country_name": "Russia",
    "country_code": 7
  },
  {
    "country_name": "Tajikistan",
    "country_code": 7
  }]
```

load and parse json data when needed using following code.

**To load json from assests folder**

`String countryJson = FileManager.getFileManager().loadJSONFromAsset(getActivity(), "countrycode.json")`;

**parse json and use**

```
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(countryJson);
                    if (jsonArray != null) {
                        final String[] items = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            items[i] = jsonObject.getString("country_name");
                        }
```

**FileManager.java**

```
import android.content.Context;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Created by gaurav on 10/10/15.
 */
public class FileManager {
    static FileManager fileManager = null;

    private FileManager(){}

    public static FileManager getFileManager()
    {
        if(fileManager==null)
            fileManager = new FileManager();
        return fileManager;
    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset(Context context,String fileName) {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(fileName);
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

Comment: And where does the FileManager class come from?

Comment: added code for filemanager class.

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry for accepting the answer so yet. I haven't tried it out, Im going to try it tonight.